# Using Webform to create a node

Tags: webforms

So i know there are answers around not using Webform, but i require the reporting and tracking functionality of webform, so please stick to using it.

I am needing to create a node based on a questionnaire that is filled out so i can then display the answers of each submission in a list view/ detailed view setup. they are stories that users are able to tell to the world then have displayed on the site.

Any ideas?

Comment: So basically you want to create nodes with webform submissions? you can do that by programatically creating nodes on webform submissions.

Comment: A guy I use to work with created a module for this though I have not used it. https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/MrAsia/1696484

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Rules module in the following way:

1. Install and enable Rules module
2. Install and enable Webform Rules (https://drupal.org/project/webform_rules)
3. Create a new rule
4. Choose the "After a webform has been submitted" event
5. Optionally set your conditions
6. Add a new action "Create a new entity" of type "Content"
7. Add the neededs action to add properties to the created entity
8. Add the save action

*Note:* You can use Tokens available with "Set a data value" .

Comment: Apologies I abandoned this project and went with making the user register and then get them to fill in a node, but you sit have given a great answer, thank you